# Opencv detect only facing up square contour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a video input from a camera. The input is a video in which I have a cube with 6 images, one on each side of the cube. I need to detect which image is facing the camera and I used SIFT descriptors for template matching but before I start using the template matcher I try to find the squares in the image with a size constraint so I can only apply the algorithm on these squares. However my problem is that in some angles the camera see the facing up image and one side image and it detects both templates. I need to detect only the square that's facing up. This is my code for squares detection:

```
def _find_squares(img):
squares = []
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)

_retval, bin = cv.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
bin, contours, _heirarchy = cv.findContours(bin, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    cnt_len = cv.arcLength(cnt, True)
    cnt = cv.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*cnt_len, True)
    if len(cnt) == 4 and cv.contourArea(cnt) > 1000 and cv.isContourConvex(cnt):
        cnt = cnt.reshape(-1, 2)
        max_cos = np.max([angle_cos(cnt[i], cnt[(i + 1) % 4], cnt[(i + 2) % 4]) for i in xrange(4)])
        if max_cos < 0.1:
            squares.append(cnt)
return squares
```

Here's a photo of the cube: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pVQ7.jpg
I only want to detect the square in which is the clock. Currently my algorithm detects both the clock and the barrel

Comment: can you post the image

Comment: For your use case, is it as simple as checking the area of each square detection and simply choosing the one with the largest area? Or selecting the square that is closest to the top of the image?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it detects this part: https://imgur.com/a/8BSth as a square aswell